# Error in MIPS when loading from $s0 address

Tags: load, mips

I'm having a problem loading from any memory address starting with s.
I can load properly from the t registers, but when i run

```
li $v0, 4
lw $t0, $s0
lw $a0, $t0
syscall
```

I Get the error:
Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: lw $t1,-100($t2)

There is something stored in $s0, so can someone explain what is wrong with my call of how to correctly call this address.

Comment: `lw $t0, $s0` makes no sense. Did you mean `lw $t0, ($s0)` (reading from memory at the address contained in `$s0`) or `move $t0, $s0` (copy the value of `$s0`)?

Answer (score 3):

Do:
`lw $t0, 0($s0)
lw $a0, 0($t0)`

instead.

Remember that you need to give an offset when you are using sw and lw.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not exactly with *any memory address starting with s*.
The problem is the same for both lines:

```
lw $t0, $s0
lw $a0, $t0
```

but Mips stops when he find the first mistake.

To use `lw` or `sw` you have to follow a format, a convention:

```
lw  $rt, offset($rs)
```

Where `$rt` is the register where you are going to load the value which is in the memory location result of sum the value that contain `$rs` with the `offset`.

For further information about that, you can read [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/load.html).

This is needed because the memory is much higher than the value that can save each register (16, 32 or 64 bits, depends of your MIPS), so you couldn't address almost nothing without the `offset`.